# Flutter iOS build fails because xCode codesign

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

Flutter iOS build fails with this exception:

```
Error (Xcode): Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign
path_to_project/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter with identity C05FA058034F7D0A4C805541BF182-
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Tried to run `flutter clean` and deleted build folder inside xcode but it didn't work.